# ternary-coded decimal numeral

Tags: number-systems, visualization

Is it possible to create a ternary clock, similar to this one, using LEDs to express ternary values?

[image: binary clock]

Comment: What restrictions do you have? Could I make a ternary clock that uses multiple colors? Could I just use one column that goes like 1,3,9,27; or would you prefer two columns that go 1,3,9?

Comment: @AlgorithmsX As I do not know how many variants exactly it could show, are there many alternative visualizations?

Comment: You could do almost anything you want with this, just like you can represent a clock in almost any way you want.

Comment: For instance, if you allow multiple colors, you could have one color represent a "1" in that place, another color represent a "2", and you can have an empty circle represent a "0".

Comment: @AlgorithmsX I thought that it being ternary, 3 colors must be used. Regarding the columns, I do not know exactly what that means. I thought about visualizing a similar concept as that of the pic but in ternary. If possible, and the number of possible representations is not really big, I'd really appreciate it if I could get an assortment thereof

Answer (score 1):

There are two major considerations you need to take into account.

The first is whether you want to convert the time into ternary digit-by-digit (i.e. each of the six digits) or number-by-number (i.e. the three numbers: hour, minutes, seconds). In the diagram above, it does the binary conversation digit by digit. In ternary, a digit by digit conversion would require you to have $1,3,9$ as your powers of three (since each digit in a decimal base is less than $10$). In a number-by-number conversation, you would need $1,3,9,27$ since the numbers representing the hours, minutes, seconds go up to $59$.

Secondly, in binary, there are only two "symbols" used to represent the number. Usually we write those symbols as $0$ and $1$; in this picture however, the two symbols are represented by the two different states of the circle (empty or filled). In ternary, there are three symbols (usually written $0,1,2$) and thus each circle would need to have three states. There are many ways to do this such as having three different colors or having a half-filled circle as an additional state. The different ways of visually representing the three symbols however is more of a artistic design decision and not a mathematical one, so the possibilities are endless.

Comment: You only need $1,3,9$ for the hours.

Comment: 2x2=4 possible representations? I'd like to check all four to see what is more easy to comprehend through the human vision

Comment: @AlgorithmsX Thanks for pointing that out. That reminds me that if the OP decides to go with a digit-by-digit conversion, then you only need $1,3$ for the tens digit of the minutes and seconds and you only need a $1$ for the tens digit of the hours.

Comment: @GJC That's 4 possible representations given the examples I gave. As for how to represent the 3 states of the led light, there are a lot of different creative ways to represent the 3 states. You could use different colors to represent the states (off/color1/color2 or color1/color2/color3), you could use intensities (off = $0$, half-intensity = $1$, full-intensity = $2$), you could use two leds (both off = $0$, left on only = $1$, right on only = $2$, both on is undefined), or if you're up to a time-dependent solution you could use a blinking pattern (off = $0$, blinking = $1$, steady = $2$).

Answer (score 0):

You need three colors to represent $0,1,2$.  An LED that can be off/red/green can do that.  Then instead of the $1,2,4,8$ stack you have $1,3,9$.  No problem.

Comment: perhaps the concept of having a binary gray-black coloring is better, gray being empty (0,A) half gray and half black (1,B) and then completely black (2,C)